# Git - If staging only marks files for commit, how Git remembers file contents after another local change?

Tags: git

In Pro Git the author says that Git staging is just a file storing which files go towards next commit. Then how does Git remember the contents of a file in staging area, even after that file is again modified in working directory?

E.g.

1. edit myFile
2. git add myFile
3. edit myFile

Now, upon commit Git checks in the file as in step 2. How does it remember the contents of file in staging, if staging is just a file marking? Does it also store file contents, upon staging instead of just the file marking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it also store file contents, upon staging instead of just the file marking?

Yes, it must necessarily do so to allow you to diff the file in the working directory with the file in the index. `git add` doesn't simply "mark files for commit", it adds the *content* of the file to the index, so the *content* of the file can be added to the next commit. Content is all Git *can* track, that's how it works: It tracks the content of files.

Answer (score 2):

When you add the file to git index, the blob is stored like any other file already tracked by git under `.git/objects` and the tree state is recorded in `.git/index`.

If you can experiment, see what happens when you delete .git/index. Every new file that was added to the index gets unstaged. Files already in your repo will be treated as deleted as there is no entry for them in the index (since there is no index.) And if you do a `git reset`, your index will be recreated and all staging details for modifications will be lost as well.  But note that the objects added will still be there, and later cleaned if the file never makes into the repo.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But deleting the index file, marks my file for removal in staging area & shows it as untracked.

Comment: @Mohnish - I was talking from a new file point of view. Re-worded it.